# Styling a decimal number with PHP

Tags: php

Just a little bit stuck, trying to find the right function to use:

```
$number = "4.999";
echo number_format($number, 2); //5.00
```

We want it to display as `4.99` - what PHP function should we use which won't round anything, just purely limit the numbers after the decimal point to two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`printf`](http://php.net/printf):

```
printf('%.2f', $number);
```

(`%.2f` prints float numbers with 2 decimal places)

---

**edit** I've read your question wrong the first time. What you are asking for is rounding down the number to 2 decimal places, then display it:

```
$number = floor($number*100)/100;
printf('%.2f', $number);
```

Comment: This still outputs as 5.00 and if I assign it to a variable it outputs as 5.004

Comment: Your edit seems to work when printing, but when assigning it to a variable it doesn't, I'm guessing replace printf with sprintf?

Comment: @Latox, yes `printf` will output the string and returns its length, whereas [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) will return the string – your original question used echo though, so I went the `printf` route

Answer (score 1):

It's actually an abuse of this function, but it works on strings and doesn't suffer from inaccuracies of a float conversion nor does it round anything:

```
echo bcadd("4.999", "0", 2);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php

Or simply:

```
echo substr($num, 0, strpos($num, '.') + 3);
```

Comment: I wouldn't know why not, except that it feels a little dirty. ;o)